# How to detect if a request was aborted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a request and then right after it I abort.

```
var x = $.get(url, function (d, e, xhr) { alert(d); });
x.abort();
```

The problem is that it executes the `success` function and returns empty data... [(example here)](http://jsfiddle.net/e5NBT/)

Is there a jQuery method to abort? or Is there a way to check if the `xhr` was aborted?

Comment: I just want to skip the `success` function when it's aborted. Is it possible to remove the `success` function assigned?

Comment: BrunoLM - Just updated my answer. Seems that you can set the `onreadystatechange` to `null` *before* you abort. I was testing this originally after the `abort()`. Works better before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/no-more-ajax-error-callbacks-fired-in-jq1-4-2-jq1-3-2-works-fine) that the `xhr` will return with status `0`. Seems to be a jQuery 1.4+ bug. On 1.3 it called the error handler.

Comment: Indeed, corresponds to status 0, but also corresponds to offline mode status code.

Answer (score 48):

The best way to detect request abortion and avoiding false positive from offline mode :

```
$("#loading").ajaxError(function(event, xhr) {
  if (xhr.status === 0) {
    if (xhr.statusText === 'abort') {
      // Has been aborted
    } else {
      // Offline mode
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Note: `xhr.statusText` may be empty string rather than the word 'abort', as is the case for Node.js. In fact, the [WHATWG Fetch specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-response-status-message) (which is unintuitively linked to by the [XHR spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-statustext-attribute)) only states *"A response has an associated **status message**. Unless stated otherwise it is 'OK'."* Also, `xhr.status` may be 0 when online, eg. for CORS requests. A better check for loss of connection is `navigator.onLine`.

Comment: We cannot get a special message from NodeJs/IIS/nginx/... since the abortion is initiated by the browser, and not sent by the server. The issue with `navigator.onLine` is the lack of context.

Comment: BTW The navigator can be in a different state from the XHR, since `navigator.onLine` state is not in real time.

Comment: if the xhr is aborted via xhr.abort("troba"), this won't work

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** Try this:

```
x.onreadystatechange = null;
x.abort();
```

Seems to work. Not sure what side effects, if any.

---

**Original answer:**

Would it be sufficient to just test the response received?

```
var x = $.get("./", function (d, e, xhr) {
    if(d) {
        // run your code with response
        alert(d);
    }
    // otherwise, nothing will happen
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Test if `data` is null to determine if the request responded correctly.

> If a request with jQuery.get() returns
>   an error code, it will fail silently
>   unless the script has also called the
>   global [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)  method.

It may be useful to handle this (from [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)).

Comment: This `.ajaxError` doesn't seems to work. Can you provide an example?

Comment: I don't think `ajaxError` will help. After `abort()` you get a successful empty response.