# How to check if ajax request was aborted by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I'm making long polling ajax requests to my server

```
$.ajax({
    url: "someurl.com", 
    success: function(resp) { ... },
    error: function() { ... }
});
```

but if there is some internet connection problems for a short period of time
Firefox 10 aborts the request and hence my script doesn't receive response from the server
(in older versions of FF there were no such request aborting).

How can I found out that my ajax request was aborted by browser? Maybe there are some event for it? Or can I force browser not to abort my ajax requests if the network connection is down?

Comment: how about looking into this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648309/how-to-detect-if-a-request-was-aborted

Comment: the difference is that the browser returns no response at all in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For XMLHTTPRequest, it gives status `"0"` saying that `request not initialized`. You can catch that status and know that `req` has been aborted.

Comment: but none of success and error functions that I pass to jQuery.ajax function is executed, so how can I get this status

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a timeout to the call?

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "test.html",
        error: function(){
            // will fire when timeout is reached
        },
        success: function(){
            //do something
        },
        timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the abort status of the jqXHR in the .fail (previously .error) function.

```
let request = $.ajax({
    // your options
})

request.fail(jqXHR,textStatus){
    if(jqXHR.abort){
        alert("Aborted")
    }else{
        alert("Other error")
    }
})
```