# Intermittent truncation of AJAX requests--how to evaluate and/or workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, http

I have a JavaScript web app that makes numerous AJAX calls (via jQuery), the largest of which posts between 50kb and 250kb.  For these larger requests, the payload is a JSON string, and I have found that a small percentage of the time, the request is truncated.  It arrives at the server, and the server throws an exception because the JSON string is broken off right in the middle.

From reviewing our logs, I can see that:

1. It happens with many different browsers (e.g., Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc.) on many different platforms (e.g., Windows 7, OS X, iOS, Android, etc.)
2. The user are able to complete their submissions.  In other words, it looks like they try again, and the same data goes through on the second try.
3. The Content-Length header of the request is larger than the length of the request string actually received by the server.

I have never been able to reproduce this problem.  But it's an ongoing issue that happens multiple times per day, and if there's any way to address it, I'd like to do that.

I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot something like this, because it's exclusively happening on a remote client.  Any suggestions?  And has anyone else experienced this, and were they able to determine the problem?

Here's the JavaScript that's generating the calls.  It works 99% of the time, and usually (always?) the user can re-initiate the request (thus executing this call a second time) and the entire request goes through;

```
    var token = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceEndpointUrl,
        data: requestData,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 9000000, // 15 minute timeout
    });
```

Comment: Where is your `success: ` property or your `.done()` method?

Comment: I didn't copy/paste the token.done() code.  Remember, the AJAX request is (very rarely) arriving *on the server* with a truncated request body (shorter than the Content-Length header).  It doesn't seem possible that the JavaScript code on the client that handles the response from the server is causing the server to *receive* a truncated response... is it?

Comment: Having the same problem, no idea how to debug this. Any luck with this?

Comment: No, I never did figure it out. At this point I'm assuming it's due to problems at the network level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if a request was aborted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648309/how-to-detect-if-a-request-was-aborted)