# Notify when terminating a jQuery Ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have learnt that $.ajax() returns a jqXHR object and you can call a number of functions on this object. We can even call jqXHR.abort() to abort an AJAX call.

My question is how do I capture that the ajax call was aborted and notify the user whenever .abort() is called.

A simple example is appreciated

Comment: Is this any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648309/how-to-detect-if-a-request-was-aborted/3648331#3648331

Comment: not much help. I need an example using jQuery 1.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **ajaxError** method should only be attached to document.

like :

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/missing.html" ) {
    $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
  }
});
```

Or 
you can try **error** method: A function to be called if the request fails.

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "url",
      dataType: "type",
      data: "data",
      success: function (response) {
         alert("Success");
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });
```

Check  **[APIDocumentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** for detailed information about error method