# Get error message from Angular 2 http

Tags: http, angular

I have the following code in my service

**myService.ts**

```
makeHttpGetRequest(url){

        return Observable.interval(config.SUPERVISOR_REFRESH_INTERVAL * 1000)
            .switchMap(() => this.http.get(url))
            .map(res => res.json())
            .timeout(config.REQUEST_TIMEOUT * 1000, new Error('Time out occurred'))

    }
```

In my component file,

**myComponent.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
        this._myService.makeHttpGetRequest(myurl)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.supervisorServers = data;
                    }

                },
                error => {
                    this.error = true;
                    console.log(error); //gives an object at this point
                    this.showError(error);
                }
            );
    }
```

I want to print the error message in case of for e.g. Invailid url.
When I print the error, I get an object (probably response object) like the following:

```
Object { _body: error, status: 200, statusText: "Ok", headers: Object, type: 3, url: null }
```

If I open this, I cannot find the error message. Is there a better way to get precies error messages?

Answer (score 10):

The error is contained in the body of the response even in this case. See the error event handler onError function:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L96

You can access it using the json method on the response:

```
error => {
  this.error = true;
  console.log(error.json()); //gives the object object
  this.showError(error.json());
}
```

**Edit**

I investigated a bit more this issue. In fact, you can't have the exact message. I mean the `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. XHR doesn't provide it. That said, you can see that the `status` of XHR is `0`. This could be an hint that there was a problem the request when sending the request (it's not actually sent).

```
error => {
  (...)
  var err = error.json();
  var status = err.currentTarget.status;
  (...)
}
```

See this question:

- [XMLHttpRequest() & net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569559/xmlhttprequest-neterr-name-not-resolved)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can access that. But for e.g. when I have an invalid url, I can't see error message in the body of the response. Is it possible to obtain an error message to show on the UI?

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, you can't have the exact message since it's not accessible within the XHR object. That said, you can rely on the `status` field of this object... I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I try error.error and work to me. Its get the Object message error.

**EDIT:**

Sorry!!

Try this:

```
            error => {
                this.error = true;
                console.log(error.error); 
                this.showError(error.error);
            }
```

Comment: You should add additional detail to make your answer fit in context better

Answer (score 1):

Using Angular 5+ you can actually just use `error.message`.

```js
 error => {
                console.log(error.message); 
                this.showError(error.message);
          }
```

In my case I am using Ionic 3 with an alert

```js
 error => {
        loading.dismiss();
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error: ',
        message:  error.message,//Displays http error message in alert
        buttons: [
                     {
                        text: 'Dismiss',
                        role: 'Yes',
                        handler: () => {}
                     }
                  ]
                });
             alert.present();
             }
```

Here is a snippet of the error object in the console when logged:
[image]

Comment: error.message gives me a big part of stacktrace too. I don't want that part. I can substring it using split('at') but that way is not clean is it? I was hoping for a better solution coming to this thread.

Comment: @arm this ultimately depends on the kind of error you receive back. I've had instances where message doesn't exist but you can navigate through the error.message instance or have cases set up based on the error type to grab what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify the error object to print its string value

```
const errStr = JSON.stringify(error);
console.log(errStr);
```