# Unable to get data from node js service to angular js 2

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular, typescript

I am learning Angular and I am trying to get data from a node js service with the help of the services in angular 2.

when I executed node js services from browser I am able to see the result but when I trying to get data in angular it throws an error.

Here I have created service in node js and from angular, I am trying to get data but it throws an error.

**node js:**

```js
    var http = require("http");
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var sql = require('mssql');
    var data;
    var config = {
        server: 'INBGMW-C037',
        database: 'InvoiceReminders',
        user: 'sa',
        password: 'psi'
    };
    app.get('/serviceline_dtl', function (req, res) {
        // connect to your database
        sql.close();
        sql.connect(config, function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            // create Request object
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.input('p_Flag', sql.VarChar, "ALL_SERVICE_LINE")
            request.output('po_Retval',sql.Int)
            request.output('po_UpdatedBy',sql.VarChar)
            request.output('po_UpdatedTime',sql.DateTime)
            request.output('po_Message',sql.VarChar)
            // query to the database and get the records
            request.execute("[dbo].[ARA_SP_DS_GetAllSLDetails]").then(function(recordSet) {
                if (recordSet == null || recordSet.length === 0)
                    return;
                // res.send(recordset);
                data=recordSet.recordsets;
                res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
                console.log(data);
                sql.close();
            })
                .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                sql.close();
            });
        });

    });
    var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
        console.log('Server is running..');
    });
```

Angular

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

    import { serviceLine } from './models/serviceLine';

    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

    // Import RxJs required methods
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

    @Injectable()
    export class HttpService {
        private BASE_URL:string = 'http://localhost:5000/serviceline_dtl';
    constructor(
        private http: Http)
    {
    }

    public getServiceLinedtl(){
        return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL`)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json());
        //.catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }

    }
```

component:

```js
    import {
        Component,OnInit ,OnChanges
    }
    from '@angular/core';
    import {
        IMyDpOptions
    }
    from 'mydatepicker';
    import {
        HttpService
    }
    from './http.service';
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        styleUrls:['/css/home.css'],
        templateUrl:'./SpotCheckStatus.html',
        providers:[HttpService]
    })
    export class SpotCheckStatusComponent  implements OnInit
    {
        constructor(
        private httpService: HttpService)
        {
        }

        ngOnInit(){
            this.httpService.getServiceLinedtl().subscribe(
                response=> {
                    console.log("VALUE RECEIVED: ",response);
                }
                ,
                error=> {
                    console.log("ERROR: ",error);
                }
                ,
                () => {
                    console.log("Completed");
                });
        }

    }
```

**the error**

`Response headers : Headers {_headers: Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)} ok : false status : 0 statusText : "" type : 3 url : null`

`_body : ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …} proto : Body`

Comment: what error get's thrown

Comment: Response
headers
:
Headers {_headers: Map(0), _normalizedNames: Map(0)}
ok
:
false
status
:
0
statusText
:
""
type
:
3
url
:
null
_body
:
ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
__proto__
:
Body

Comment: above one is the response which i get

Comment: is your angular app running at the same port of your node server?

Comment: to see details about the error check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669087/get-error-message-from-angular-2-http

Comment: port numbers are different

Comment: it is possible that you're facing CORS problem...look at this https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: Thanks. Problem is with CORS. the above link is resolved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone else came to this question: When you have front-end and back-end running on different ports/domain (in this question, I assume you're using angular-cli so the default domain is http://localhost:4200) and the server is running in http://localhost:5000, you should enable CORS to be able to reach the server. If you're using express (as the OP) check this link to enable cors in your node server: https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Kind regards.